# What's the Busybox default shell?

Tags: linux, shell, busybox

My guess is this defaults to Bash, but would like to know for sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The default shell in BusyBox is [ash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_shell).

Comment: To be more precise, it is the `dash` derivative of `ash`as per busybox shell source code at https://web.archive.org/web/20210119235542/https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell/ash.c

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers That is misleading. Although `busybox ash` was originally based on an ancient (2001) version of `dash` (mostly, since historical `ash` was not portable and is not maintained), modern `dash` is significantly different than `busybox ash` (mostly: `dash` has removed a lot of features). Slackware also maintains a distant fork of `ash`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not bash, is a one small file replacement for many small linux/unix utilities like sh and the files utilities

It's written with minimum size in mind and with embedded systems as target where space is a precious resource.

Check for more info: http://www.busybox.net/about.html